# Why doesn't the PHP __set() magic method fire when updating a property of an object stored as a private property?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

Given the following design pattern...

```
class Person
{
    private $properties = array(); // will eventually hold an address object

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (!empty($this->properties[$name])) {
            return $this->properties[$name];
        }
    }
}

// create a generic object to hold address data
$home_address = new stdClass();
$home_address->postal = '12345';

// instantiate a new person object and assign $home_address as property
$customer = new Person;
// __set() magic method fires just fine
$customer->home_address = $home_address;

// now try to set a property of the address object
// __set() magic method DOES NOT fire
$customer->home_address->country = 'USA';

// best work around i can find is to assign the current
// address to a temporary variable and then re-assign
// it back to the property
$temp_address = $customer->home_address;
$temp_address->country = 'USA';
// __set() magic method fires just fine
$customer->home_address = $temp_address;
```

Why doesn't the `__set()` method fire when I add / update a property (for example, `country`) on the private property of `home_address` directly?

The only work around I have found is to use a temporary variable and completely overwrite the `address` private property in order to fire the `__set()` method.

Any best practice advice or am I not understanding the best way to use the __set() method here?

Comment: `__set()` is only called when you're setting a non-existent property.

Comment: @Maerlyn I believe that's partially true... It also fires when you set a private *existing* property (as you can see in the final couple of lines of code in my work-around example).

Comment: From the outside that's a non-existent property.

Comment: But why should it be called in the second case? You actually call `__get` to fetch `$customer->home_address` value, which is `stdClass` object. With `->country`, you update this object, not the `$customer`.

Comment: @Maerlyn Ah, yes, you're absolutely correct.  So I suppose I should change my actual question to "What is the best practice way for me to update properties of objects that are stored as private properties"? Is my work-around the "best" way to do this?

Comment: have you tried your work arroung by reference `$temp_address =& $customer->home_address;
$temp_address->country = 'USA';`
that way wou wont have to reset home_address afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are looking at this correctly.

When you try to set `$customer->home_address->country`, you are trying to set a property on the `stdClass()` object that is set to `home_addresss` property of `$customer`.  This would in no way invoke a setter on `$customer`.

Your initial setting of `home_address` does in invoke the `__set()` magic method as `home_address` is not defined as a property on `Person` class.

Comment: Yep, I think I understand now.  So I suppose I should change my actual question to "What is the best practice way for me to update properties of objects that are stored as private properties"? Is my work-around the "best" way to do this?

Comment: You should use a public setter.

Comment: I would agree with @FabienWarniez Typically one would expose public setters/getters to work with private properties. IMO relying on magic method is typically bad coding practice.

Comment: Definitely agree, unless you are doing something very funky, which I doubt is happening here.

Comment: @MikeBrant So you'd recommend something like `$customer->updateAddress($home_address);` where `updateAddress` is a public method that sets a private `_address` property explicitly? Would you still recommend the same approach where `$customer` may contain up to 30-40 properties?

Comment: @JaredCobb I actually probably wouldn't update addresses via the Person object at all.  I sounds to me like you might need a class for address information rather than using stdClass. Why should the `Person` class have any address logic at all (other then knowing it can store an address object). If you wanted to do things like validate address information (i.e. zip codes really exists - that sort of thing), this logic should not be coupled to the `Person`

Answer (score 1):

You are updating country on stdClass while you have defined __set method for Person. Updating stdClass has nothing to do with invoking __set method for Person class.

Answer (score 1):

If a method does not exist in your class (or is private in your case), PHP calls __set in case you defined a generic catch all setter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that the code:

```
$customer->home_address->country = 'USA';
```

Breaks down internally as:

```
$temp = $customer->__get('home_address');
$temp->country = 'USA';
```

Therefore the internal state of the `$customer` object doesn't change. I think you'll need to do something like:

```
$address = $customer->home_address;
$address->country = 'USA';
$customer->home_address = $address;
```

Or, if you really need to set/update properties like this, why not make it a public property and not worry about `__get()` and `__set()`?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the work-around snippet I have at the bottom with `$temp_address`.  Thanks!

Comment: @JaredCobb that's all well and good, but if you need to set/get properties like this, why are they private/not-actual-properties in the first place?

Comment: In this simple example that's a good option, however in my real world code I have a couple dozen properties that I need to run additional various logic against (when setting)... One simple example would be data scrubbing an address differently than data scrubbing an email. It looks like (as others have recommended) that I should probably rely on public setters / getters such as `$customer->updateAddress($home_address)` and then the `updateAddress()` method would run additional logic before setting the private property. Would you agree with that approach as well?